# why model name in eloquent are not as same as table name?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

When you create model in laravel for eloquent, the User model is treated like a users table.  Why is that? Can we use an exact table name for the model?

Answer (score 6):

I think more than anything it's convention. I don't see why you couldn't create a `Users` model for your `users` table, but a `User` is an instance of `users`, which is why it's done that way. You can always specify the table the model uses with:

```
protected $table = 'name_of_table';
```

which can be different than the model name. For example, a `Data` model can use the table `userdata`, as long as you specify that.

Hope that helps.